# Parsing an int variable

Tags: c, parsing, int

I have an int array filled with numbers of the format:

```
1160042
5900277
3200331
1001
1370022
```

Is there a way that I can parse these ints without converting them to a string first? I'm looking to use the 00 as the token, assigning everything before it to one temp variable and everything after 00 to a second temp variable

Comment: Use `getchar()` and parse it byte by byte manually.

Comment: What does it even mean to "parse" a number without making a string out of it. Do you mean is there a way to mathematically find the zero digits and what's before and after them? If so, then yes, there's a way to do that. Think `% 10`.

Comment: that's exactly what I mean. Thanks

Comment: I think you should take a step back and ask yourself why you are opposed to an intermediary string... feels like premature optimization to me. With a string this becomes trivial: `char *p = strstr(line,"00"); if (p) { p[-2]='\0' a = atoi(line); b = atoi(p); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void splitInt(int v, int *first, int *second){
    int pre = -1;
    int zeroCount = 0;
    int denomination = 10;
    int temp1, temp2;
    *first = *second = -1;//not found
    while(temp1 = v / denomination){
        temp2 = v % denomination;
        if(pre == temp2){
            if(++zeroCount==2){
                *first  = temp1;
                *second = temp2;
                return ;
            }
        } else {
            zeroCount = 0;
        }
        pre = temp2;
        denomination *= 10;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int data[5] = {1160042, 5900277, 3200331, 1001, 1370022};
    int i, temp1, temp2;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        splitInt(data[i], &temp1, &temp2);
        printf("%d, %d\n", temp1, temp2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 00 is a custom semantic for these numbers and is in base 10.
However, as the machine is working on base 2 and is not aware of the meaning of double 0 in the provided numbers, you'll probably have to convert it to string in order to parse it the way you described.